# How can I make 4 elements rotate in a circle?

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

First of all I would like to say I am a complete beginner to jquery.
I would like to make these divs move round in a circle in a clockwise direction with a 500px diameter. How could i go about doing this?

```
<div id="move0" class="textBox"></div>
<div id="move1" class="textBox"></div>
<div id="move2" class="textBox"></div>
<div id="move3" class="textBox"></div>
```

Please look at my website http://tragicclothing.co.uk/T-Shirts.html 
This is what I want to be able to happen

Steps:

1. Click on button in centre
2. Images appear around this button (fade in)
3. Rotate images slowly around this button

Comment: AD formatting: ever seen toolbars? There's a **curly braces** button on it that formats selected text to code... :) It also helps to read [Markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that will help you format your text while writing it.

Comment: AD your question: should you DIVs be circles as well? And since you say you don't know jQuery, so you know CSS3 maybe? Because it can be done completely by CSS3 animations. Do you have any link that shows how end result should look like? A youtube video? an animated image? Flash animation? Anything?

Comment: I cant find anything no. What I want to happen is when you click on T-shirts the images appear in the div boxes and just rotate round the t shirts button slowly? http://tragicclothing.co.uk/T-Shirts.html

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-roundrr/ this will show the images in circle ..

Comment: Sorry I didn't know you could use CSS3? Do you know how I could go about it using CSS3?
thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: Yeh @XMen I just had a look at that and it is not what I am looking for really. The only similarity is that the images are in a circle. 
But thanks for commenting

Comment: Then explain compared to XMen's example what you want. Apparently it's not easy to understand what you want. Can you draw an image and attach it to your question?

Comment: Hi Robert sorry about this I am such a rookie.
Does this help?
step 1) Click on button in centre

step 2) Images appear [fade in]

step 3) rotate around button in centre slowly

Comment: [This link](http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/) is not an end solution to your problem but it gives you an idea how to properly do it using CSS3. Add your middle positioned button and then you'd only be manipulating CSS classes to initiate particular movement scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

> ***Note:*** This is not my code, but was written by [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/) on her respective blog.

### CSS3-only circular animation

This particular [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/zXPzY/) shows one element being rotated around some central point. CSS of it is actually really simple:

```css
@keyframes circle {
    from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes inner-circle {
    from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}

body > div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    color:orange;
    font-size:100px;
    line-height:1;
    animation: circle 5s linear infinite;
    transform-origin:50% 200px;
}

div > div {
    animation: inner-circle 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div><div>☻</div></div>
```

Basically all you'd have to do is convert these to CSS classes and then just add a click handler on your central button that would fade-in your images around it and add a CSS class to them so they would start rotating as well.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please I don't quite understand.
like what is a click handler? And convert what exactly to css? and to what?

Comment: @user1806497: Ok so you don't know anything about CSS either? :) Well... Before you start doing sites I suppose the main thing is **to learn the technology**. And that includes your server side and client side (CSS, HTML and Javascript - along with jQuery).

Comment: @user1806497: Current CSS styles define animation directly on any DIV (and DIV within DIV). You don't want that. You only want it applied to particular elements when they have some particular CSS class. And when they do, the start rotating. Learn CSS; Learn jQuery and you'll know what I'm talking about. **We're here to help you, not to develop stuff you should be developing**. One doesn't go for a 250km long cycling ride at start of season. If you don't know the technology, use what you know. Then learn and upgrade your product.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, and you can add as many `INPUT` elements in the HTML as you need.

(**Update**: the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYyJs/1/) link.)

```js
// fetch all DIV.txtBoxRotate elements inside DIV#txtBoxRotateContainer
var txt = $('#txtBoxRotateContainer .txtBoxRotate'), txtLen = txt.size();
// utility functions to convert degrees to radians    
var deg2rad = function(a) { return a*Math.PI/180.0; }
// rotation settings
var angle = 0, speed = 1, delay = 10, r = 250;

(function rotate() {
    for (var i=0; i<txtLen; i++) {
        // we know how many elements we have, so we will add an even
        // amount of degrees of angle for each of them to complete a circle
        var a = angle + (i * 360 / txtLen);
        // we reposition our element by using {sin(a),cos(a)} for our initial
        // position. If you want to change direction, switch to {cos(a),sin(a)}!
        // then we multiply the x,y by our radius and add our radius to center
        // then element. You may add another offset if you want (ex: y+r+(Math.sin...)
        $(txt[i]).css({top: r+(Math.sin(deg2rad(a))*r), left: r+(Math.cos(deg2rad(a))*r)});
    }
    // increment our angle and use a modulo so we are always in the range [0..360] degrees
    angle = (angle + speed) % 360;
    // after a slight delay, call the exact same function again
    setTimeout(rotate, delay);
})();  // invoke this boxed function to initiate the rotation
```

```css
#txtBoxRotateContainer { height: 800px; }
.txtBoxRotate { position:absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txtBoxRotateContainer">
    <div class="txtBoxRotate"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/uganda12-hp.jpg" alt="Google!" /></div>
    <div class="txtBoxRotate"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/Googles_14th_Birthday-2012-2-hp.gif" alt="Google!" /></div>
    <div class="txtBoxRotate"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/bohr11-hp.jpg" alt="Google!" /></div>
</div>
```

**Note**: the original code had `INPUT` elements (because this is what I assumed with your `class="textBox"`), thus the `id` and CSS `class` names. You may use whatever naming you want.

Comment: Great use of sin and cos forgot used it in college , it would be better if you explain the logic in detail

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I am wanting images to rotate not text boxes.

Comment: @user1806497, well, you can simply change the content of the `DIV` containers for images. The script doesn't care about the content :)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, yes, I thought about it. I was lazy :)

Comment: @user1806497, here, I changed the input boxes to images. Cheers!

Comment: Look how it looks on my page http://tragicclothing.co.uk/T-Shirts.html ? I want the images to appear after you have clicked the t-shirt button. And why when you scroll down do they move faster?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var elements = $('.textBox');
      var length = elements.length;
      var offsetX = 300;
      var offsetY = 300;
      var radius = 250; //radius = diameter(500px) / 2 
      var incr = Math.PI * 2 / length;
      var progress = 0;

      setInterval(function() {
        progress++;
        elements.each(function(i) {
          $(this).css({
            top: offsetY + Math.sin(i * incr + ((progress / 100) * Math.PI * 2)) * radius,
            left: offsetX + Math.cos(i * incr + ((progress / 100) * Math.PI * 2)) * radius
          });
        });
        if (progress >= 100) {
          progress = 0;
        }
      }, 50);
    });
```

```css
.textBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="move0" class="textBox"></div>
<div id="move1" class="textBox"></div>
<div id="move2" class="textBox"></div>
<div id="move3" class="textBox"></div>
```