# How to align HTML table cells as circle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create some sort of compass in HTML, I've came this far:

```css
.devicecompass {
  display: inline-block;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
td a div {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
td a div:hover {
  opacity: 0.0;
}
td#e {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: fff;
}
td#router a div {
  background-color: #0a0;
}
td#n5 {
  background-image: url("http://www.eurodk.lv/images/catalogue/directional/&product-view-small&nanobeam400.jpg"); 
}
/* .17 */

td#nno5 {}
/* .18 */

td#no5 {}
/* .19 */
```

```html
<!-- 5 GHz devices -->
<div class="devicecompass">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="nw5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.31">
          <div>nw5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="nnw5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.32">
          <div>nnw5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="n5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.17">
          <div>n5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="nno5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.18">
          <div>nno5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="no5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.19">
          <div>no5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="wnw5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.30">
          <div>wnw5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="e">nw</td>
      <td id="e">n</td>
      <td id="e">no</td>
      <td id="ono5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.20">
          <div>ono5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="w5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.29">
          <div>w5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="e">w</td>
      <td id="router">
        <a href="#">
          <div>compass</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="e">o</td>
      <td id="o5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.21">
          <div>o5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="wsw5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.28">
          <div>wsw5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="e">sw</td>
      <td id="e">s</td>
      <td id="e">so</td>
      <td id="oso5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.22">
          <div>oso5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sw5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.27">
          <div>sw5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="ssw5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.26">
          <div>ssw5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="s5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.25">
          <div>s5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="sso5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.24">
          <div>sso5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td id="so5">
        <a href="http://10.26.51.23">
          <div>so5</div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

But I would rather like to align the cells (=gray small circles) in a circle so it looks more like a compass, how would that work?
It is not important if the cells are outside the table-border or inside (=black large circle), important is, that the cells are aligned like a circle.
I tried to paint it, not a perfect circle, but it should look similar like this:
[image]

When I search SO and the web for HTML tables/cells aligned as a circle, I find much examples how to round corners of the table into a circle but not to align the cells within the table as a circle.

Or am i thinking the wrong way and should choose another way to acomplish that?

Comment: Why on Earth are you using a table for this layout? A more general search would help https://www.google.co.uk/search?%7Bgoogle:acceptedSuggestion%7Doq=css+elemnts+in+circle&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+elemnts+in+circle&gws_rd=ssl#q=css+elements+in+circle

Comment: Dont use tables for layoiuts unless needed.in this situation table is not needed

Comment: thanks, that's why i asked for another way, because i didnt know better. i'll look into the first result of your google search.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xRxzBJ

Comment: Interesting @Paulie_D I think I'll adapt that (get rid of Jquery) to answer this question :-)

Comment: The jquery just adapts it to work with any number of items. It's not one of mine...I found the basic code on SO somewhere and adapted it so in that respect this is probably a dupe. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307383/how-can-i-make-4-elements-rotate-in-a-circle

Comment: @Paulie_D I've converted it to standard javascript (have a look at my answer if you're interested)

Comment: thanks very much - looks very neat, would it be possible without javascript? if yes, i would prefer that solution, if not i'll stick with your great answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mind using javascript?

If not here's a solution for you, @Paulie_D commented a link to it, so I've adapted it to not use Jquery.

```js
function calcCircle(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var container = a[i].parentElement,
      width = container.offsetWidth,
      height = container.offsetHeight,
      radius = width / 2,
      step = (2 * Math.PI) / a.length;

    var x = width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(step * i) - a[i].offsetWidth / 2;
    var y = height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(step * i) - a[i].offsetHeight / 2;

    a[i].style.left = x + 'px';
    a[i].style.top = y + 'px';
  }
}
calcCircle(document.querySelectorAll('#compass > .point'));
calcCircle(document.querySelectorAll('#compass > .inner-compass > .point'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#compass {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  /* the radius of .item (half height or width) */
  margin: 30px;
}
#compass .point {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #777;
}
#compass .inner-compass {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#compass .inner-compass .point {
  background: #ccc;
}
#compass .center-point {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="compass">
  <div class="point">E</div>
  <div class="point">ESE</div>
  <div class="point">SE</div>
  <div class="point">SSE</div>
  <div class="point">S</div>
  <div class="point">SSW</div>
  <div class="point">SW</div>
  <div class="point">WSW</div>
  <div class="point">W</div>
  <div class="point">WNW</div>
  <div class="point">NW</div>
  <div class="point">NNW</div>
  <div class="point">N</div>
  <div class="point">NNE</div>
  <div class="point">NE</div>
  <div class="point">ENE</div>
  <div class="inner-compass">
    <div class="point">E</div>
    <div class="point">SE</div>
    <div class="point">S</div>
    <div class="point">SW</div>
    <div class="point">W</div>
    <div class="point">NW</div>
    <div class="point">N</div>
    <div class="point">NE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-point">Compass</div>
</div>
```